# Clean/Dirty Merged Collection

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a single Entity, let's call it Bottles. This entity has among others a Boolean property called Default.

I have a screen with a DataGrid where I can add edit and delete Bottles. The requirement for validation is that there can be only one "Default" Bottle. In other words, only one Bottle can have it's Default property (a checkbox in the datagrid) set to true. I already handled screen validation, however I still need to handle the DataServiceValidation for multi-user scenarios.

How do I get the merged collection of clean/dirty entities? Please note this is a Visual Studio LightSwitch question.

Answer (score 1):

The one thing to keep in mind that queries like the following

this.Bottles.Where(b => b.Default).Any())

will get executed against the data store. It will not reflect the state of any entities that may have been modified locally but not yet saved. Once you call the execute method and apply a where operator to the results

this.HourTypes.Where(h => h.DefaultType).Execute().Where(h => h.DefaultType).Any()

the second Where will be executed against the local version of that entities that we returned from the data store.

In order to solve your problem, I think you will need to execute a local query against the current changes as well as a data store query. I have included some validation logic below which I think will solve your problem.

```
partial void Bottles_Validate(Bottle entity, EntitySetValidationResultsBuilder results)
{
    // Only run the Default Bottle validation logic for Bottles that will be Default Bottle.
    if ((entity.Details.EntityState == EntityState.Added 
            || entity.Details.EntityState == EntityState.Modified) 
        && entity.Details.Properties.IsDefault.IsChanged 
        && entity.IsDefault)
    {
        // Query the current set of changes to ensure there are not multiple Default bottles in it.
        bool hasMultipleNewOrModifiedDefaultBottles = this.Details.GetChanges()
            .OfType<Bottle>()
            .Any(e => (e.Details.EntityState == EntityState.Added 
                    || e.Details.EntityState == EntityState.Modified)
                && e.IsDefault
                && e != entity);
        if (hasMultipleNewOrModifiedDefaultBottles)
        {
            results.AddEntityError("Only 1 default bottle can exist.");
        }
        else
        {
            // Grab the current Default Bottle from the data store if one exists and ensure it 
            // is still marked as the default. This needs to account for the scenarios in which
            // the Bottle has been changed to no longer be marked as the Default
            // and the scenario in which the Bottle is being deleted.
            Bottle defaultPersistedBottle = this.Bottles.Where(b => b.IsDefault)
                .SingleOrDefault();
            if (defaultPersistedBottle != null
                && defaultPersistedBottle.IsDefault
                && defaultPersistedBottle.Details.EntityState != EntityState.Deleted)
            {
                results.AddEntityError("Only 1 default bottle can exist.");
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the Bottles_Validate method. Example (not tested):

```
partial void ApplicationUsers_Validate(ApplicationUser entity, EntitySetValidationResultsBuilder results)
{
    if(entity.Details.EntityState != EntityState.Unchanged && entity.Details.Properties.Default.IsChanged && entity.Details.Properties.Default.Value)
    {
        //changed/created a default bottle
        if(this.Bottles.Where(b => b.Default).Any())
        {
            results.AddEntityError("Only 1 default bottle can exist.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem here is if I add more than one entity at a time, for instance in DataGrid view, how does one new entity in the validate function know about the other new entity if each time validate is called only one new entity is validated?

Comment: In fact the code yields very odd results. If an existing entity has a Default value of true, but I set it to false and set a new entities Default value to true, the LINQ expression yields true, since the unchanged existing entity's original Default value is true. But if I use the same where condition on the results of the LINQ expression, that second LINQ expression returns false. So if I do this **this.HourTypes.Where(h => h.DefaultType).Execute().Any()** I get true, and if I do this **this.HourTypes.Where(h => h.DefaultType).Execute().Where(h => h.DefaultType).Any()** i get false.